# how to solve core_rt tag lib issues in liferay tab?

Tags: jsp, liferay

i have got the following error while working with tabs concept in view.jsp:
The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application while using jstl. i have added the jar file jstl-1.2.jar file. the following is my view.jsp: can any one help me for correct code?

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.security.permission.*" %>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil" %>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.theme.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>


//A renderURL is created because we need to render a jsp page you need to use //renderURL we can also  pass parameters if required

<%
//We must Specify a default value for tabs. In this example it is sunday. Else it //will throw an error.
String tabValue = ParamUtil.getString(request, "tab", "sunday");
String tabsURL = "/html/tab" + tabValue.trim() + ".jsp";
String tabNames="Sunday,Monday,Tuesday" ;
String tabVal="sunday,monday,tuesday" ;
%>

<liferay-ui:tabs
names="<%=tabNames%>"
tabsValues="<%=tabVal%>"
param="tab"
url="<%= portletURL %>"
/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following in `web.xml`

```
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

#### Edit

It is always better to include libraries from Liferay portal itself instead of including external jars directly in `WEB-INF/lib` of the portal. You can include the JSTL jars from liferay by specifying following in your `liferay-plugin-package.properties` instead of including the `jstl1.2.jar`:

```
portal-dependency-jars=\
    jstl-api.jar,\
    jstl-impl.jar
```

<sub>Note: The edit is done based on the comments</sub>

Comment: File "/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld" not found. where i will get this?

Comment: "liferay-plugin-package.properties" open that file and add "c.tld" from UI

Comment: can u explain clearly..i did not understand properly.i dnt know where to add that c.tld file. i have only jstl1.2.jar file only not c.tld file.please help me

Comment: i have added that c.tld.but i got the exceptions:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV and Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV

Comment: do you have jars inside your web-inf/lib directory?

Comment: no but in referenced libraries i have added the jstl1.2.jar and standard.jar i added i am getting:                                   Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV

Comment: you need to add jars inside web-inf/lib directory

Comment: i have added but, all these are not storing in web-inf?lib these are storing referenced libraries

Comment: try adding "jstl-api.jar and jstl-impl.jar" from liferay-plugin-package.properties file